# received an e-mail offer from the hiring manager but only "employment guarantee" from HR?

Tags: hiring-process, new-job, contracts, relocation

> **tldr version:**  I have a job offer in another country, but in the time it has taken to get HR to agree a start date, parts of the offer such as temporary accommodation have changed, and they say I won't get my formal contract until my first day, should I insist on seeing the contract before I book my travel (which I will need to pay myself)?

Comment: 1: Paragraphs exist for good reason.  Use them.  2: Proofread post you write before committing them.  3: Given this example of your presentation style, attention to detail, and respect to those you are communicating with, I simply can't take what you say at face value.  Without hearing HR's side of things, I don't have confidence we know what really happened.

Comment: Although it's not easy to understand your question, I think this is a legal question and you need to consult a lawyer ASAP.

Comment: Why would you commit to relocate to another country if it's only for 1 month? Also edit the question to make it easier to read.

Comment: Think I've made it readable without changing the intent, not really legal, more common sense required.

Comment: Just in case, did you Googled the company name or any address, if they gave you one? Glassdoor  reviews may be useful in this case.

Answer (score 3):

> but with no salary mentioned or anything else (so not an actual offer
>   letter)

You are correct. They haven't given you a written offer. So It would not be wise to start the process of quitting your job and moving to a new country without knowing at least what they will be paying you.

Will you get to see a contract? I have no idea, I have never seen anything beyond an offer letter.

You will also need in writing what they will pay towards your relocation expenses.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the written contract you have no idea what you are actually agreeing to. When you are required to travel to another country before you see it, it will be very hard to refuse, no matter what is in it. That puts you into a very bad situation to negotiate any bad clauses.

You didn't say where you are moving, but you should be warned that this is the way many human traffickers operate: Lure people into the country with great promises of a dream job, and when they left everything behind to relocate, force them to sign a contract with horrible conditions for a job which has nothing to do with what was promised. I am not saying that this is what they might try to do to you, but the tl;dr version you left of the question fits into the pattern.

Comment: +1 for bringing up this. Although we don't know if OP is men or female, this smells bad. Even if they are a 100% legal company, OP's account of past communications with HR make it sound shady enough to run away.

Comment: @Trickylastname It's not just women who are victims of human trafficking. There are lots and lots of facets of it. A large business where victims of human trafficking are exploited is construction work, for example. Forced sex workers are just those which make the best selling headlines in media.